# Bluez: Difference between "Connect()" method return and "Connected" signal

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

According to the Bluez API documentation ([Device API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt)) the return of the `Connect()` method indicates a successful connection of one or more profiles:

> void Connect()
>
> (skipped)
>
> If at least one profile was connected successfully this method will
> indicate success.

At the same time there is a `Connected` property, which is described as:

> boolean Connected [readonly]
>
> Indicates if the remote device is currently connected. A PropertiesChanged signal indicate changes to this status.

In practice it appears that the return of the `Connect()` method and the arrival of the `PropertiesChanged` signal notifying about `Connected` property being set to `true` happen few seconds apart.

When running bluetoothctl:

```
[bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

Following messages were captured on the D-Bus:

```
method call time=1646854334.904791 sender=:1.521 -> destination=org.bluez serial=50 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX; interface=org.bluez.Device1; member=Connect
signal time=1646854336.902736 sender=:1.128 -> destination=(null destination) serial=10521 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.Device1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "Connected"
         variant             boolean true
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]

method return time=1646854339.349113 sender=:1.128 -> destination=:1.521 serial=10522 reply_serial=50
```

Which tells us that:

- The `[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes` appears on the screen when the `Connected` property changes to `true` as reported by the signal (`time=1646854336.902736`).
- The `Connection successful` message appears when the `Connect()` method returns (`time=1646854339.349113`).
- These events occur 2.4 seconds apart.

**The question is what the difference between these two events and which one actually signifies that the Bluetooth device was connected?**

(When disconnecting the device, the `Disconnect()` method return and the arrival of the signal occur `0.003` seconds apart).

---

Environment: Linux kernel: `5.4-179`, Bluez: `5.62-r3`, Systemd: `249.9`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrival of the `Connected` signal indicates the establishment of the low level link ([ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Connection-Less)).

The return of the `Connect()` method indicates that at least one [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile) was connected successfully (higher level connection).